# TCL get value of concatenated variable

Tags: tcl

`x` is a list of device names (device-1, device-2, device-3)
There is a variable created for each device1 by concatenating the string port so you end up with `$device-1port`.

looping over x creates

```
[expr $${x}port-2000 ]   #x is device-1 so it is trying $device-1port-2000 which throws error.
```

I would like to get the numeric value of `$device-1port` into a variable without a dash.

```
set xvar $${x}port

[expr $xvar-2000 ]
```

or can i wrap the `$${x}port` in something within the `expr` statement.

Comment: The entire set of rules for Tcl syntax is here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read a variable with interpolations in its name, use single-argument `set`:

```
set withoutadash [set device-${x}port]
```

Generally, it's better to use arrays for this kind of thing.

Comment: Maybe my example of device names should be clearer.  The names will vary so the list will be more like this. (hhh-ggg, yyy-ggg, mmm-nnn).

Comment: I think you get the idea: (1) get rid of expr with double-substitution, which doesn't help, (2) use `[set $name_of_var-with-dashes-or-anything]` instead of `$$name_of_var-with-dashes-or-anything` for variable access.

Comment: The solution for me seems to be: set xvar [set ${x}port];

Answer (score 0):

One of the nicest ways to work with such complex variables is to use the `upvar` command to make a local “nice” alias to the variable. In particular, `upvar 0` makes a local alias to a local variable; slightly tricky, but a known technique.

```
upvar 0 ${x}port current_port
```

Now, we have any read, write or unset of `current_port` is the same as a read/write/unset of the port with the awkward name, and you can write your code simply:

```
puts [expr { $current_port - 2000 }]
set current_port 12345
# etc.
```

The alias will be forgotten at the end of the current procedure.

---

Of course, you probably ought to consider using arrays instead. They're just simpler and you don't need to work hard with computed variable names:

```
set x 1
set device($x,port) 12345
puts [expr {$device($x,port) - 2000}]
```